# How do we find validation error of linear regression and elastic-net using Scikit-learn and python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

When do we use test set and validation set while calculating errors?
 I have linear regression and elastic-net models working. I am new to Machine learning with Scikit-learn and Python.

**I am trying to solve this problem.**
[Data Set: UCI Machine Learning Forest Fire data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsQ0F.png)

Comment: This would be a better fit for stats.stackexchange: except it might already be a duplicate. Checking out [Difference between test set and validation set](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set) and the related questions may be a good start

Answer (score 0):

You can use the test set when you build the model by use the method of minimizing the errors.After you build the model, you can calculate the actual error by using the validation set and then use the error to correct the parameter.I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you. But, how do I correct the parameters using validation set error?

Comment: I am trying to solve this problem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HsQ0F.png It will be great help if you can help me in algorithm of learning curve and how to do that in Scikit-learn.